# Vertex Standard VZ-28 - Unable to import settings into software due to password

Tags: software, radio-programming, motorola

I had been trying to program my Vertex Standard VZ-28 radio on my Windows-7 Machine using the VZ-28 V2.0.2 software.
I had entered the password under "General" menu for the radio and now while trying to program it from the computer, I get the error shown below in the screenshot:

[image]

Can someone please help me locate the user interface either on the radio or the software from where I can enter/disable the password to unlock read/write?

Thanks,
73

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this issue by connecting the radio to my computer and writing the default values from the software into the radio without reading it first.

The password blocks the read operation and not the write operation.

Steps:

1. Connect the Radio to the computer.
2. Open Vz-28 software and Goto "Radio Info" option.
3. Choose frequency range as per need (136-174MHz or 400-470MHz).
4. Set all other params as needed.
5. Goto "Program" menu on the top.
6. Click write.